# how many cores uses gbak (firebird) on restoring?

Tags: linux, firebird

I'm restoring db, and I see that firebird uses only one core of my CPU for gbak and fb_smb_server:
[image]

Is it normally? I've 4 cores in my CPU.
**CpuAffinityMask** parameter in firebird.conf is commented out.

Comment: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3958 http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1365 http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2992

Comment: Know that CpuAffiityMask is 1) only relevant on Windows, 2) only relevant for SuperServer and 3) commenting out will use the default value (which is 1, aka use first core).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the tickets linked by Val Marinov in the comments ([CORE-1365](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-1365), [CORE-2992](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-2992) and [CORE-3958](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3958)), a restore in Firebird is currently entirely linear and will only use a single CPU core.

Firebird 5.0 will introduce support for parallel workers during backup, restore and index creation/rebuilds.